# Weird behaviour using 2 cell dentifiers in a tableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm playing with the cell identifier in a TableviewController, I'm using storyBoard with dynamic cells.

I set 2 cells with 2 identifiers and used a custom row height:

[image]

In my viewDidLoad, I  just insert some checking information to a mutableArray:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _arrayCellContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            [_arrayCellContent addObject:@"white"];
        }
        else
            [_arrayCellContent addObject:@"Brown"];
    }
}
```

My cellForRow delegate method is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* identifierCellSlim = @"cellSlim";
    static NSString* identifierCellFat = @"cellFat";
    UITableViewCell *cellSlim = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierCellSlim forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cellFat = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierCellFat forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row%2 ==0) {
        cellSlim.textLabel.text = self.arrayCellContent[indexPath.row];
        return cellSlim;
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    else {
        cellFat.textLabel.text = self.arrayCellContent[indexPath.row];
        cellFat.detailTextLabel.text = @"yalla";
        return cellFat;
    }
}
```

The final outcome is:
Even cell row heights, not costumed. Why is that? (I know I might work it out with the right delegate method, but I just want to know why the IB not doing his job)

Also in the beginning the cells appear to be in the right color but when I click some of them they will transform to the other cell,

Does clicking the cell change the indexPath ? 
 Example:

[image]

Comment: Do not dequeue both types of cells becaus you only need one of them. Do the if first and dequeue only that type of cell that you really need.

Comment: The table view has a row height property, which can only have one value, so I don't think you can do what you want without using the delegate method. If you have only one cell, and change its height, the table's row height property is automatically adjusted as well.

Comment: Thanks, i moved each "dequeue" method in each "if" statement and that solved the problem with the colors.

Answer (score 0):

You are dequeuing both cells in the same method call.

You should check for which cell is necessary for the given NSIndexPath and dequeue the relevant cell.